# What does "unladen" mean, specifically

Tags: suspension

The service manual says:

> "Perform the final tightening of the rear suspension member and axle
> installation position (rubber bushing) under unladen condition with
> tires on level ground".

Does this just mean to remove the jack and tighten the nuts to spec torque with nothing significant in the back seat/deck etc?  i.e. full weight of the vehicle on the suspension

(I know what the dictionary definition of 'unladen' is, but it seems a bit ambiguous since the vehicle is a load on the suspension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the vehicle **is** a load on the suspension and that is the load that should be applied when you finally tighten those suspension joints.

If you ignore that, then the bushes get pre-loaded incorrectly and fail sooner than they should.

You should check the workshop manual for the vehicle as it will often say a full tank of fuel or 1/2 tank... But draining fuel out on a customer's car is not usually done...

Answer (score 3):

Unladen means the vehicle is on the ground but no people or cargo is loaded into the car.